# How to create an exe file for adobe air project?

Tags: flash, air, flex4, installation, flash-builder

I created a adobe AIR project in flash builder 4.5. I created its native executable file, but when I double click it, it first installed and then I was able to run it. My question is:

- Can I create an executable that I don't need to install before using it.
- Or can I do this some other way?

As in MFC when we build project it create an executable that does not need to be installed. Thanks

Comment: Publishing from Flash Pro as "Windows Projector" produces an .exe file that doesnt need to be installed (just double-clicked). But not sure if it would work with AIR classes or how to create it from Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done in the past to achieve the same result is use c#.
First i would create a blank document than load into the library's "adobes" into the project, from there you can pack everything together and it will create a exe the same as any other windows exe with an installer, you can use the c# installer to pack.

Comment: I actually don't want to create an installer. As we see in MFC project, when we build project, it creates an .exe file that we can run anywhere without installing it. I want to achieve the same functionality but for Adobe Air project.

Comment: I have done this through c# aswell, i embed my flash project inside the c# project then create an exe

Comment: I previously created the same project in MFC. But its exe size was larger than required. If I go with this approach using C#. It will also increase the exe size. size is the only constraint here.

Answer (score -1):

It will have the drawback if the target system doesn't have Adobe AIR runtime installed then your exe file will not run.